# Toddler painting app/game for Windows

Tags: windows, children

We have a living room Windows PC connected to the TV and our 2 year old is interested in it. I think he could play with it if we found the right app. Ideally it would be very simple and foolproof. What I mean:

- Full screen and not possible to navigate away or otherwise interact with the OS without some kind of keyboard sequence (ESC would be fine, or a CTRL+ALT+??? type).
- Replaces the mouse cursor with something more visible and fun.
- Teaches about moving a mouse and clicking, by exploration and discovery, not instruction (he is 2).

Some things I tried are Paint (the one that comes with Windows) and an app called Paint 4 Kids. The first one is too complicated, the second one is close but the interaction with the OS inevitably means he will click away and get into the browser or something else that just basically breaks it for him.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is like what you are looking for, but what about http://www.babysmash.com/index.htm